# Celery task subprocess stdout to log

Tags: subprocess, celery

I have a celery task which calls other python script external to Django application with `subprocess`. This program have some `print`'s in it, and I want to have these print's in my celery log file or in my database. When I set `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` in Django `settings.py` file, everything works fine. If I don't set this setting, celery task log subprocess stdout only when it exit. It seems like `p.stdout.readline()` is blocking.

`run-test.py` is a long process, couple of minutes, but it print what it's doing. I want to capture this.

```
@shared_task
def run_tests(scenario_path, vu):
    basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    config_path = '%s/../../scripts/config.ini' % basedir
    cmd = ['python', '%s/../../scripts/aws/run-test.py' % basedir, '%s' % config_path, scenario_path, str(vu), str(2)]
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        if line != '':
            logger.info(line)
        else:
            return
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be very useful, using select for polling instead of blocking on readline.

https://gist.github.com/bgreenlee/1402841

```
child = subprocess.Popen(popenargs, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE, **kwargs)

log_level = {child.stdout: stdout_log_level,
             child.stderr: stderr_log_level}

def check_io():
    ready_to_read = select.select([child.stdout, child.stderr], [], [], 1000)[0]
    for io in ready_to_read:
        line = io.readline()
        logger.log(log_level[io], line[:-1])

# keep checking stdout/stderr until the child exits
while child.poll() is None:
    check_io()

check_io()  # check again to catch anything after the process exits
```